# Overhead with Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq-to-sql

We are currently experiencing performance issues with a website written in ASP.NET MVC 4, specifically overhead with regard to Linq-to-SQL, thus resulting in (among other things) the CPU jumping to 100% for every page request where Linq-to-SQL is used.

I am analysing the application with ANTS Performance Profiler 8.5 Pro, and experiencing the same results in both dev and production environments. However the performance is far worse in the production environment than in the development environment.

Through ANTS I seem to have narrowed it down to overhead when instantiating Linq-to-SQL data contexts and performing a very simple query like for instance:

```
using (var db = new D.DataClassesDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master"].ConnectionString))
{
    db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

    HttpContext.Cache["WebPageTemplateCapabilities"] = (from x in db.Clients
                                                        where x.ClientID == this.ClientID
                                                        select x.WebPageTemplateCapabilities).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out exactly why a simple query like should cause such a performance hit. This code snippet takes up to 1.5 seconds to run, which is insane when compared to the same query execute in SSMS. I am at this point assuming that the high CPU usage may be a result of any database communication by this website.

What am I missing? This is for the record the very first data context instantiated and query performed during the website's life cycle.

Comment: How and where this code is called?

Comment: It makes up the constructor of an object first instantiated through the instantiation of another object in my base controller.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly managing the connection? (This could prevent possible connection pooling), e.g. db.Connection.Open() and db.Connection.Close()

Comment: @PaulZahra Are you suggesting a static context with explicit connection handling?

Comment: You should probably be using Entity Framework instead of LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Fred That would require a major architectural restructuring, and what makes you suggest that?

Comment: @Maritim, it seems EF is what Microsoft is betting on. The ASP.NET projects use EF by default. Also EF have the benefit of being open source. It seems everyone is or will be using EF. LINQ to SQL feels like it is a thing of the past that is on its way out and will probably be deprecated soon. So it might be a good idea a plan a migration to EF.

Comment: @Fred I've heard the opposite, however such a migration is not very feasible at the moment. I know for a fact that lots of sites are running Linq to SQL without such a tremendous performance hit, there has got to be some way to solve this.

Comment: show us your connection string (without authentication details)

Comment: @Maritim with your using .. new context, you are creating a new context for the code snippet, effectively making it static, but without explicitly opening and closing the connection you are leaving it open for the .net code to manage its connectivety. By the way how big a database are we talking about here? i.e. how big is the context your creating?

Comment: P.S. I would remove HttpContext.Cache["WebPageTemplateCapabilities"] and replace with a var just to eliminate caching/memory issues and to ensure it is just the L2S

Comment: @jgauffin SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=notsosecretdatabase;UID=xx_develop;PWD=supersecretpassword

Comment: @PaulZahra I am purposely storing it in the cache so that it can be re-used by other visitors to the website, thus limiting the amount of queries performed.

Comment: @Maritim Fair enough, but for the purpose of testing L2S eliminate it.

Comment: @PaulZahra I can now confirm that it is not related to the HttpContext.Cache

Comment: @Maritim Okidoki, if you just create a method that *only* instantiates the context (and does nothing else), is that slow too?

Comment: It is an old version of sql express? See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504719/70386

Comment: @jgauffin I am only running sql express in the dev environment, and enterprise in the production environment. The problem exists in both environments. For the record the express is 2012 and the enterprise is 2008 r2.

Comment: L2S can be a slow pig, is the profiler reporting something like DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall taking a silly time? I suggest also testing the speed of first calls, but also of second calls, is the second call something like 4 times faster? If so you could create a new dbcontext on app start and dispose of it to eliminate the initial slowdown.

Comment: @PaulZahra In my case it's IProvider.Execute

Comment: @Maritim see my edit to me previous comment, try subsequent calls.

Comment: @PaulZahra That improves the instantiation time of subsequent data contexts, but not calls. I'm starting to believe that it might be because the Clients table is in another database (Master). Calls to the Client database do not seem to be a problem according to ANTS. Both databases are on the same server and accessible with the same username and password.

Comment: @Maritim ahh... is it indexed?

Comment: @PaulZahra By primary key.

Comment: @Maritim Can you use SQL Profiler to see the SQL that is generated?, run this in SSMS with the option to show the actual execution plan enabled. If relevent SSMS will suggest indexes that should improve the performance.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using Linq to SQL AND you make calls to the same query multiple times then I'd recommend using compiled functions.  The query above can be written as follows:

```
private static Func<DataClassesDataContext, string, string> MyCompiledFunction =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext pContext, string pClientID) =>
            (from x in pContext.Clients
             where x.ClientID == pClientID
             select x.WebPageTemplateCapabilities).SingleOrDefault();
```

You don't specify the return type or the client ID so I have assumed they are strings.

Be aware that there is an overhead whilst the function is compiled for the first time - after that it is MASSIVELY faster, we were getting 5 or 6 times faster in our code.  If it's only ever called once then don't bother.

Comment: It's only called once, and then stored in the HttpContext.Cache as illustrated by the code sample.

Comment: Well don't bother then.  If you do have other methods that match this then definitely rewrite them.  I find LINQ to SQL extremely slow at times and this has helped us immeasurably

Comment: I have lots of methods that match this, but I fear that compiled queries may actually cause more harm than good. What other measures did you implement to boost performance?

Comment: I can't see why it would.  We also turn off object tracking if we don't need to update the DB and set "UpdateCheck" to never on the design pane (again if there is no updates needed).  For updating I tend to batch up objects before committing them, or in worst case write a stored proecedure to do it.

Comment: This article is useful http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/06/24/five-tips-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: Article on complied queries http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-5-X

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `SingleOrDefault`. The method must guarantee that there is only one result which matches your query. You should use `FirstOrDefault` instead which just fetches the first entry (if any).

I would also avoid open several DB connections for the same request (as it seems that you do since you use a dedicated connection for just that query).

Instead share the same connection for all HTTP request related queries. It's true that ADO.NET connection pooling exists, but it will still give you overhead. Especially if there are several users browsing your site.

You can use a HTTP module

```
public class ConnectionModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var db = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Items["DbConnection"] as IDbConnection;
        if (db != null)
            db.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        connection.Open();
        ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Items["DbConnection"] = connection;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can access the connection from anywhere by using:

```
var connection = (IDbConnection)HttpContext.Current.Items["DbConnection"];
```

You can of course replace the connection with your `DbContext` instead.

As for Unit Of Work. In my world a HTTP request always represents one unit of work. If not, the HTTP request is too broad. (But that depends of course on how you have designed your web site)

Comment: I'll definitely attempt your solution with regard to FirstOrDefault versus SingleOrDefault. It is recommended all over the web that you use one context pr unit of work, how do you recommend implementing this connection sharing? A static context?

Comment: @Maritim: Example added.

Comment: In my experience a shared context even on a class basis can go horribly wrong, i advocate a more granular approach to Unit of Work.

Comment: It goes wrong if you share it over multiple threads. Can you give an example on when it did go wrong in a limited context such as a HTTP request?

Comment: Working on legacy code on a huge project, can't give examples soz.

Comment: P.S. Don't think the issue is with singleordefault...If your result set returns 0 records:

    SingleOrDefault returns the default value for the type (e.g. default for int is 0)
    FirstOrDefault returns the default value for the type

If you result set returns 1 record:

    SingleOrDefault returns that record
    FirstOrDefault returns that record

If your result set returns many records:

    SingleOrDefault throws an exception
    FirstOrDefault returns the first record

Comment: @PaulZahra SingleOrDefault iterates the entire enumerable before returning, FirstOrDefault does not. This performance difference is best illustrated with huge data sets, which I don't have in this case.

Comment: @Maritim It only iterates the whole enumerable if it is two records long, i.e. it only looks for a second record, if it is more than one it throws an exception. I admit firstordefault is generally faster and I tend to prefer it in most cases, but I don't think singleordefault would introduce such a large overhead as OP is experiencing. Not sure but I think it works as I've stated for L2S, but for L2O I think you are correct.